# iOS Safari action extension work with change URL

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I want to make Mobile Safari action extension with UI for changing URL.

ActionViewController.swift

@IBAction func done() {

```
let newURL : String = "http://google.com"

let extensionItem = NSExtensionItem()
let jsDict = [ NSExtensionJavaScriptFinalizeArgumentKey : [ "newURL" : newURL ]]
extensionItem.attachments = [ NSItemProvider(item: jsDict as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: kUTTypePropertyList as? String)]

self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [extensionItem], completionHandler: nil)
```

}

Action.js

```
var Action = function() {};

Action.prototype = {

run: function(arguments) {
},

finalize: function(arguments) {

    var newURL = arguments("newURL");
    if (newURL){
        location.href = newURL;
    }
}

};

var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new Action
```

But after running 'self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [extensionItem], completionHandler: nil)'

console shows as below:

> [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

Please help me.

Comment: I have the same error in the console when trying to replace selected text with the text I generate in the Action Extension. Did you got solution?